buenas, tengo problemas con la libreria mapStruct en sopring boot
Tengo la libreria de importada de mapStruct y me reconoce las anotaciones @Mapper y Mapping pero los source y target me marcan error.
Cabe aclara que los atributos que están dentro si son los nombres de las entidades y Dto las dependencias en buid.gradle corren sin problemas y estoy usando java 21.
Si alguien me puede decir que esta mas se lo agradecería mucho, gracias.





El castellano tiene el "punto aparte". Usalo y tus mensajes serán más entendibles.

Lectura altamente recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 Luego de leer, edita la pregunta para que tengas más chances de obtener respuesta. Saludos :D
